# how to generate series data in kusto for datetime column along with values

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to generate 24 hour data(time & status value), where I want to generate series between the missing time range along with its values in KUSTO. Using the below logic I am able to generate series but its taking the first record as 1.00:00:00, but i want my first record to start with actual value. Can you help me with this?

datatable(Time:timespan, Status:int)
[
timespan(1.00:10:00), 4
,timespan(1.04:00:00), 2
,timespan(2.12:00:00), 4
,timespan(2.20:00:00), 2
]
| make-series take_any(Status) default=int(null) on Time step 1h
| mv-expand Time to typeof(timespan), series_fill_forward(Status) to typeof(int)

[image: Series i am trying to generate]
Above screen shot (snip shot has the actual data) is the data that i am actually working, above is the example with datatable.

Comment: Please clarify how doe the result set look like (What is the 1st/last timespan?)

Comment: Actual data 
08:00:10 4
08:01:36 2
08:07:15 4
08:12:56 4
08:17:24 2
 
Expected Data 
08:00:10 4
08:01:10 4
08:02:10 2
08:03:10 2
08:04:10 2
08:05:10 2
08:06:10 2
08:07:10 2
08:08:10 4
08:09:10 4
08:10:10 4
08:11:10 4
08:12:10 4
08:13:10 2
08:14:10 2
08:15:10 2
08:16:10 2
08:17:10 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modifications to the code posted in question and able to achieve the result.

**Changes are below**

1. Created the *starttime* value using summarize min() with `toscalar` method to get greater than equal to value in `where` clause. This helps us filter rows from the start time as you requested.
2. Observed that in screenshot you used *step 1m* but the posted code has `step 1h`. I have used *1m*. This query will not work with 1h as your *starttime* has value for minutes.

**Code:-**

```
let tbl = datatable(Time:timespan, Status:int)
[ timespan(1.00:10:00), 4 ,timespan(1.04:00:00), 2 ,timespan(2.12:00:00), 4 ,timespan(2.20:00:00), 2 ] ;
let starttime = tbl
| summarize min(Time);
tbl | make-series take_any(Status) default=int(null) on Time step 1m
| mv-expand Time to typeof(timespan), series_fill_forward(Status) to typeof(int)
| where Time >= toscalar (starttime)
```

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc4Zl.png)

Comment: issue is resolved. Thank you